# auth0 try button linkedin is using v1: This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs

Tags: auth0, linkedin-api

When I use the try button on auth0.

Menu 'Connections' -> 'Social'

then I use 'try' link on Linkedin

Linkedin is using for test the v1 version, and not the v2 version for linkedin, so when i try to login in on linkedin  I get the error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile (status: 410 data: {\n  \"errorCode\": 0,\n  \"message\": \"This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs\",\n  \"requestId\": \"RN0AITTUWB\",\n  \"status\": 410,\n  \"timestamp\": 1545991044990\n})"
}
```

the try linkedin button is using a link like that (old link v1 method):

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=...
```

accord docs from linkedin this is not more valid for news apps

is a bug from auth0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: The problem was a bug in auth0, sadly auth0 hidden this information some months, creating a big confusion, some months ago the fixed this problem

OLD:
I've solved this, just, creating a new linkend app (31 december 2018).

go to linkedin developers, and click on 'Create app':

https://www.linkedin.com/developers#
    appname: test1linkedin

tab 'auth':
    OAuth2 settings,  Redirect URL's:

```
    https://yourdomain.auth0.com/login/callback
```

(very important to work with aut0)

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an existing Issue in Github [here](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/62) and a pull request open [here](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/pull/61). I recommend commenting on these to bring it to the

> All developer applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Portal after January 14, 2019 have access to the LinkedIn v2 API by default. Alternatively, if your developer application has made a successful LinkedIn v1 API request from September 1, 2018 to December 17, 2018, your developer application has immediate access to the v2 API.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: my app was create after 17 december, this pr solve this problem?

Comment: is not normal, lock v11 from auth0 is giving the same error